# multidimensional array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was unable to to multidimensional array sorting when myarray size is different. It was fine for first array as second and third array cannot be sort due to it size. May i know any expert can assist in this.

*this sample just have three myarray in fact i have thousand myarray define therefore i cannot use different name for three different array.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
for($num = 0; $num < 3; $num++)
{
    if ($num == 0)
    {
        $myarray = array(
                    array('a' =>199, 'c'=>"text"),
                   array('a' =>70, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   array('a' =>599, 'c'=>"text"),
                   array('a' =>700, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   array('a' =>310, 'c'=>"tezt")
                   );
    }
    else if ($num == 1)
    {
        $myarray = array(
                    array('a' =>24, 'c'=>"text"),
                   array('a' =>82, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   array('a' =>73, 'c'=>"tezt")
                   );
    }
        else if ($num == 2)
    {
        $myarray = array(
                    array('a' =>88, 'c'=>"text"),
                   array('a' =>72, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   array('a' =>350, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   array('a' =>650, 'c'=>"tezt"),
                   );
    }

        print '<pre>';
        print_r($myarray);
        print '</pre>';

        //remove duplicate copy
        $inputdes = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $myarray)));       
        $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $myarray)));

        foreach ($inputdes as $key => $row) {
            $pricesortdesc[$key]  = $row['a'];
        }
        array_multisort($pricesortdesc, SORT_DESC, $inputdes);

        foreach ($input as $key => $row) {
        $pricesort[$key]  = $row['a'];
        }
        array_multisort($pricesort, SORT_ASC, $input);

        $prod_Price = $inputdes[0]['a'];
        $prod_Price1 = $input[0]['a'];
        $prod_Price2 = $input[1]['a'];
        $prod_Price3 = $input[2]['a'];

        echo $prod_Price.''."<br/>";
        echo $prod_Price1.''."<br/>";
        echo $prod_Price2.''."<br/>";
        echo $prod_Price3.''."<br/>";

        //reset array
        unset($myarray);
        $myarray= array();
        $myarray= null;

}//end for num

?>
```

Comment: I don't know what are you doing but there's must be a better way. Please share the goal of your code.

Comment: Add to your question the output you want from this.  The answer I posted yesterday is not what you wanted.  Please detail what you are looking for.

Comment: Array will be print out first ASC 70, 199, 310, 599, 700 DESC 700 (just one data enough ) then it will print second ASC 24, 73, 82 DESC 82, then it will print third array ASC 72, 88, 350, 650 DESC 650.. What i found the error so far is due to name Myarray used for three time, even it has been reset it still store sizeof(Myarray) = 5. The first time it store sizeof(myarray) =5. But the second and third array which less than sizeof 5..